# How to reuse filter inputs in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I'd like to have `<Input>` filter component as reusuable component. So instead of:

```js
// list.js
<Filter {...props}>
  <TextInput source="abc" />
  <SelectInput source="foo"  choices={[
    { id: 'bar', name: 'bar' },
    { id: 'baz', name: 'baz' },
  ]}/>
</Filter>
```

I'd like to have:

```js
// my-select-input.js
export const MySelectInput = props => (
  <SelectInput source="foo"  choices={[
    { id: 'bar', name: 'bar' },
    { id: 'baz', name: 'baz' },
  ]}/>
)
```

```js
// list.js
<Filter {...props}>
  <TextInput source="abc" />
  <MySelectInput />
</Filter>
```

Unfortunately position of exported component in filter toolbar is different than the rest of "normal" input components. My suspicion is that it gets decoration as it would be "normal" input component.

Answer (score 2):

React-admin's `<Filter>` introspects its children to build a list of filter names. If one of the children has no `source` (or no `label`), then it won't be able to list it in the filters dropdown.

The fix to set the source as defaultProps.

```
// my-select-input.js
export const MySelectInput = props => (
  <SelectInput source="foo"  choices={[
    { id: 'bar', name: 'bar' },
    { id: 'baz', name: 'baz' },
  ]}/>
)
+MySelectInput.defaultProps = {
+ source: "foo",
+};
```